# Type inference involving return type, wild card, and intersection type

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to declare an interface that contains a method which will return a list of things that implement both `Comparator<Object>` and `Action`, i.e.

```
<T extends Comparator<Object> & Action> List<T> getThings();
```

This compiles fine, but the problem comes when I try to call this method. I want to be able to do this:

```
List<Action> things = getThings();
List<Comparator<Object>> things = getThings();
```

When I try to do this I get the following compilation error:

```
 incompatible types; no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that
 java.util.List<T> conforms to java.util.List<javax.swing.Action>
 found   : <T>java.util.List<T>
 required: java.util.List<javax.swing.Action>
```

The following doesn't work either:

```
List<? extends Action> things = getThings();
List<? extends Comparator<Object>> things = getThings();
```

Another way to achieve this effect is to create an empty interface that extends both `Comparator<Object>` and `Action` and use that as the return type, i.e.

```
public interface ComparatorAction extends Comparator<Object>, Action { }
List<ComparatorAction> getThings();
```

But I don't want to have to do this. There's got to be a way to do what I want, right? Any ideas?

Thanks!

P.S. I'm having a tough time coming up with a good title for this post so feel free to change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also parameterize the method(s) from which you call `getThings()`.  For instance:

```
public static <U extends Comparator<Object> & Action> void main(String[] args) {
    List<U> l = getThings();
    Action a = l.get(0);
    Comparator<Object> c = l.get(0);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
List<? extends Action> things = getThings();
List<? extends Comparator<Object>> things = getThings();
```

**edit** That was my first reaction. Then I thought about it and I didn't think the inference could work, so I deleted the answer.

Checking spec again, they should work. It does compile in JDK7, but fail in JDK6. I guess there's a bug that they have fixed.

**edit 2** no... I read the spec(JLS3#15.12.2.8) again, and now I don't think the inference should work. JDK6 was correct in rejecting the inference. (I doubt JDK7 introduced a new bug; it's possible that inference rules are updated, so JDK7 is correct according to new rules. I'm not sure)

According to JLS3, first there is a wildcard capture, a new type parameter `W` is introduced, which has upper bound `Action`. Then inference has these initial constraints:

```
List<W> >> List<T>
Comparable >> T
Action  >> T
```

The first constraint yield equality constraint `T=W`, and that's it, inference is done.

Now the compiler will check to see if the inferred `T` satisfies its bounds, that is, whether

```
W :< Comparable
W :< Action
```

The answer is no, the 1st bound cannot be satisfied. (IntelliJ shows a nice error message(better than javac's):  "Inferred type '? extends Action' *(i.e. W)* for type parameter 'T' is not within its bound; should implement Comparable")

**edit 3** the question is whether there should be a wildcard capture prior to inference. that's unclear to me. If there shouldn't be, then we have

```
List<? extends Action> >> List<T>
Comparable >> T
Action  >> T
```

which yields

```
T :< Action
T :< Comparable
```

therefore `T=Comparable & Action`

Comment: Thanks for the research & explanation!

Answer (score 0):

When you return a `List<T>` like that, `T` refers to some (unknown) type that is a sub-type of `Action` and `Comparator<Object>` and is a (preferably the lowest) common super-type of all elements in the list. If such a type does not exist, you are probably going to run into problems.

If you don't care what `T` is, you can use a type variable, like Dave Costa suggests, or you can use a wildcard

```
List<? extends Action> l = getThings();
List<? extends Comparator<Object>> l2 = getThings();
```

Comment: You appear to be correct. (According to irreputable, only in java <= 1.6).

Comment: I wish I could do this but apparently this is only supported in JDK7. See @irreputable's answer.